# Public methods should not have multidimensional array parameters, sonar source

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I trying to rewrite in order to fix this part of code due displays an issue on sonar source**Public methods should not have multidimensional array parameters**

```cs
public class Example1
{
    public string Test(string a, string b, string[][] c)
    {
        var example2= new ...;
        return example2.Test(a, b, c);
    }
}
public class Example2
{
    public string Test(string a, string b, string[][] c) {
        return base.Test(a, b, c);
    }
}
public interface IExample
{
    string Test(string a, string b, string[][] c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a compiler error/warning. This is a rule defined by `SonarSource` which literally means:

> Exposing methods with multidimensional array parameters requires developers to have advanced knowledge about the language in order to be able to use them. Moreover, what exactly to pass to such parameters is not intuitive. Therefore, such methods should not be exposed, but can be used internally.

[More information can be found here](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-2368)